# Should one push or pull the leg when performing a piriformis stretch?

Tags: stretching, glutes

Should  one push or pull the leg when performing a piriformis stretch?

---

I have seen both versions:

[image]

([image source](https://backintelligence.com/piriformis-syndrome-treatment/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190326013734/https://backintelligence.com/piriformis-syndrome-treatment/)))

[image]

([image source](http://pt-helper.com/phone/tablet/knee---hip.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190325012021/http://pt-helper.com/phone/tablet/knee---hip.html)))

Answer (score 1):

The Piriformis is a bit different than most muscles.  It changes from EXT RO to a INT RO when you Flex your Hip above 90 degrees.

There are quite a few ways to stretch this, and a ton of images on google that are backwards or just confusing.  Stick to the basics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to https://sportsrehab.ucsf.edu/hip:

- if one pushes then it stretches the piriformis. Demo: https://youtu.be/XI8gbfMKNnk
- if one pulls then it stretches the gluteus (I don't know which one). Demo: https://youtu.be/wMxV1O2UCG8

Note that https://sportsrehab.ucsf.edu/hip is only mentioning the seated piriformis stretch and not the supine piriformis stretch, but I am assuming it is stretching the same muscles ([Is the seated piriformis stretch complementary or redundant with the supine piriformis stretch?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/40010/3806)).

Comment: Downvoter: please explain. I don't mind the downvote, but I would very much like to learn what information is incorrect for my own sake.

Comment: You said "if one pushes" in both bullet points